# Symfony Doctrine: An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE: Syntax error or access violation: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a problem when this line is executed in my controller:
`$organizationRepository->add($organization, true);`

I received this error:
An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' at line 1

And I can watch that an exception is throwed during this query:
'INSERT INTO organization_setting (relation_contact_company, shopping_types, currencies, calculate_return_date, organization_id, delivery_paper_id, sticker_template_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', array(), array())

I also have an eventListener on this entity on the events : prePersist, postPersist (which made another flush), and onFlush.

I saw that it could be due to reserved words in SQL, but I don't have any reserved words...
Could someone help me?
I don't know how to print the real sql request which throws the error and how to solve it.

---

Edited :
When I remove the flush in my PostPersist event it works. But I would like to know why it didn't work...